# How do I execute commands serially inside a shell script?

Tags: node.js, shell, unix, sh, direnv

I want to write a shell script to execute some commands ***in sequence*** (the next one starts only after the previous has finished and so on). I've never written a bash script before and I couldn't find the appropriate sequence.

I know that in the terminal you do things like `yarn this && yarn that && yarn other` and it works but I don't know the equivalent inside a shell script.

```
#!/bin/sh

direnv allow

# now wait for direnv allow to finish

direnv reload

# now wait for direnv reload to finish

yarn start:server
```

Comment: This is the *default* behavior in shell; the shell waits for each command to exit before starting the next one.  If you want the script to continue without waiting, you have to explicitly suffix the command with `&`.  So if your script isn't working the way you want, I suspect the cause is something else.

Comment: like said that's the default behavior. Maybe you are interested in running each command in background? (https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Job-Control) : "If a command is terminated by the control operator ‘&’, the shell executes the command asynchronously in a subshell...."

Comment: The direnv commands log some stuff on the terminal. When I execute the above, I don't get the direnv logs, the server starts and only when I exit the server do I then get the logs of the direnv commands on the screen. This made me think that the commands might not be executing in the correct order, but if you're right then it's just a timing "bug" in the way things are logged on the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

The shell will execute each command one after another serially as written.  Servers often daemonize, i.e. fork() and have the parent return.  They usually have `-f` flag to suppress that behavior, precisely because you may want that serial behavior.